# how to dump filtered data rows and columns from csv to excel using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file say Test.CSV which have columns and data values like

Column A Has values like T1,T2,T2,T1
Column B has values like P1,P2,P2,P1

Now i want to dump T1,T2,P1,P2 into a new excel sheet after checking/filtering how many T1's/T2's and how many P1's/P2's of A & B respectively are present in Test.CSV so that my new file Test2.xlsx once saved should look like

T1=2,P1=2,T2=2,P2=2

Also please let me know if i want to change the Column name of T1/T2/P1/P2 in my new excel sheet to T1-New/P1-New etc, is it possible during dumping process?

Any help in this would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to count the values in your CSV columns:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\Test.CSV'

$colA = $csv | Group-Object 'A' | select Name, Count
$colB = $csv | Group-Object 'B' | select Name, Count
```

Sample code for putting a name=count pair into an Excel sheet:

```
$xl = New-Object -COM 'Excel.Application'
$xl.Visible = $true

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Add()

$val = "{0}={1}" - f $colA[0].Name, $colA[0].Count
$wb.Sheets.Item(1).Cells.Item(1, 1).Value = $val

$wb.SaveAs("C:\path\to\Test2.xlsx")
$wb.Close()

$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, i still face a problem...now when i run the Group cmdlet i get to know how many in Total A & B values are present like for example it returns 20 & 20 respectively....What i want to know is out of this 20 in Column A how many times T1 appeared and how many times T2 appeared..Similarly for Column B....Any sample code would be really appreciated.... Do i need to put this like           $colA = $csv | Group-Object 'A' | select "T1", Count

Comment: `"T1"` is a value of a property, not the name of a property, so you can't select it like that. Pipe the result of the selection into another filter: `... | select Name, Count | ? { $_.Name -eq 'T1' }`.